# Make files truly immutable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xfs

I'm currently in the works of adding a third back-up that is Immutable. This all works fine from Veeam > Linux Ubuntu with XFS on a scsi disk. The files are locked for the days that is set in Veeam. However I've realised that it's still technically possible to remove the immutable setting by using chattr -i [filename].
This means that in the worst case scenario that the Root user is compromised the files can still be removed, making it in my opinion not truly Immutable. So far I can't find any options to disable chattr, if possible at all do i even want to do this?

Are there any other routes i could/should take? I'm a newbie when it comes to Linux so bare with me.

Comment: If you want a truly immutable backup, you must physically disconnect the backup media from the computer after you made the backup and store it in a safe place.

Answer (score 1):

> The files are locked **for the days that are set in Veeam.**

Meaning, once those days pass, Veeam must be able to remove any "immutable" protections that you have set (and it must be programmed to remove them). If you `chattr +i` all files and disable the ability to undo that, your disk will just keep filling up until you can't make *new* backups anymore.

But if Veeam software is able to delete old backups, then root will also be able to delete old backups. There's no way around that except not letting root (or the veeam UID) get compromised in the first place. So instead focus on preventing unwanted access to the server in general, e.g. not share root credentials between backup servers and "normal" servers.

Comment: Veeam does delete the files after the retention period is over. In the directory a seperate file is created next to the backup files named .veeam1.lock which contains the following:
LockData><File Name="Immutable TestD2022-07-05T140010_C60C.vbk" ImmutableTillUtc="2022-07-12 12:06:25" Finalized="true" /></LockData>

Comment: It does delete them _now,_ but if you make it impossible to remove the `chattr +i` even for root, then how is Veeam going to do that?